# Como centrar conteúdo com dimensões dinâmicas em CSS?

Tags: css, html5, css3, bootstrap-4, flexbox

Estou a usar Bootstrap 4, que é baseado em flexbox(propriedades/dimensões dinâmicas). Criei um Datapicker, com um input e um icon do lado direito.

```
<div class="col-md-3">
   <div class="input-group date" data-provide="datepicker" style="flex: 0 0 auto;">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" class="datepicker">
      <div class="input-group-addon" style="justify-content: center;align-items: center;flex: 0 0 25px;">
         <i class="fa fa-md fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Quando tento centrar o icon, com

```
style="justify-content: center;align-items: center;flex: 0 0 25px;"
```

a imagem fica assim

[image: imagem]

```js
console.log($date = "data");
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
  format: 'dd/mm/yyyy'
}).on('changeDate', function(e) {
$date = $('.datepicker').datepicker('getDate');
  console.log($date);
});
```

```html
<!-- Bootstrap CND -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <!-- Datapicker css -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.8.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.8.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.8.0/locales/bootstrap-datepicker.pt.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
     <div class="input-group date" data-provide="datepicker" id="sandbox-container" style="flex: 0 0 auto;">
   <input type="text" class="form-control" class="datepicker" data-date-format="dd/mm/yyyy" data-date-autoclose="true" data-date-today-highlight="true">
   <div class="input-group-addon" style="justify-content: center;align-items: center;flex: 0 0 25px;">
    <i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true" style="align-self: stretch"></i>
   </div>
  </div>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**[update]** 02-03-2019

Substituir

```
<div class="input-group-addon" style="justify-content: center;align-items: center;flex: 0 0 25px;">
```

por

```
<div class="input-group-addon d-flex  align-items-center justify-content-center" style="flex: 0 0 25px">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não está funcionando pq essas classes do `flex` vc tem que usar no pai que tenha `display:flex`. Além disso, não tem necessidade de usar os estilos na mão, pois o próprio Bootstrap tem classes de `flex` para fazer esse alinhamento corretamente usando as classes `d-flex` e `align-items-center` como vc pode ver aqui https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />

<div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="input-group date" data-provide="datepicker" style="flex: 0 0 auto;">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" class="datepicker">
        <div class="input-group-addon d-flex  align-items-center" style="">
            <i class="fa fa-md fa-calendar ml-2" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Boa ajuda. Para o meu código ter o resultado esperado, tive que acrescentar o alinhamento pelos eixo xx, por isso adicionei a class "justify-content-center". Para além disso, preciso que o container tenha 25px, por isso acrescentei o style "flex: 0 0 25px".
Edite a sua resposta nesta linha:
<div class="input-group-addon d-flex  align-items-center justify-content-center" style="flex: 0 0 25px">

Assim poderei validar. Obrigado pela ajuda, agora compreendo melhor o funcionamento do bootstrap.

Comment: @PedroCorreia Entendi, no casso desses ajustes finos as vezes precisamos criar algumas classes extra mesmo. Se vc acredita que o problema foi resolvido e a resposta de ajudou considere marca-la como Aceita, nesse ícone `✔` abaixo das setinhas no lado esquerdo da resposta :) Assim o site não fica com perguntas abertas pendentes sem resposta aceita. Vc pode remover a aceitação caso apareça outra resposta que te atende melhor. Abs